During testing with thunder client whole data coming but data not coming by specific id or parameter
I am working for a Backend application, When I am testing with Thunder Client data is not coming by id
Here is the screenshot

Error is
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
Database Connected
I'm listening on port 4000
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'MongoClient'
    |     property 's' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with constructor 'ServerSessionPool'
    --- property 'client' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1159:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:272:14)
    at getUserById (D:\server\controller\users.js:27:32)   
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at param (D:\server\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)

controller\users.js
const getUserById =  (req, res, next) => {
    const userId = req.params.userId;

    try {
        const user =  userService.findUserById('_id', userId)
        if (!user) {
            throw error('User not found', 404)
        }

          return res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }
};

userService code
const User = require('../models/User');


const findUserById = (key, value) => {
    if (key === '_id') {
        return User.findById(value);
    }
    return User.findOne({ [key]: value });
};


module.exports = {
    findUserByProperty
};

I tested the whole with so many id & parameters and changed those id & parameters, but the problem is the same

userService code is added

Your module.export syntactically incorrect. When you are exporting a single module you should use module.exports = module-name.And you can also send module(single & multiple) within {} but with a key-pair not like the way you did in the code.  In the newly shared script I didn't find anywhere findUserByProperty that you are exporting. Please check all these mentioned aspects and let me know.

For more information on module.exports you can check this link   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-export-module/

The problem is async / await
The solution code
const getUserById = async (req, res, next) => {
    const userId = req.params.userId;

    try {
        const user = await userService.findUserById('_id', userId)
        if (!user) {
            throw error('User not found', 404)
        }

        return res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (e) {
        next(e)
    }
};



TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Perhaps const user in controller\users.js has its own circular reference that's why you are getting this error.
This is one of the most common error in Node.js & express.js which occur when an object refers to itself by any means that JSON.stringify() can't handle.
And in your code return res.status(200).json(user); are doing the same as it also send response converting it into JSON response.
You will get plenty of resources online on this topic. So I am not sharing any resource link.
But to avoid this issue You can install and import a npm package flatted which is upgraded version of circular-json which is now deprecated. And then use it in this manner to avoid the error.
const { stringify } = require('flatted');

return res.status(200).json(stringify(user));

For more info on flatted package you can go to these links.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/flatted
https://github.com/WebReflection/flatted#flatted
Try this solution .I believe it will work.
NB: please add express tag in your question

Thank you for your post, I am checking your solution...

@jamj You should also check userService module. The error might be coming from that code.Since you didn't share the code of userService I am not sure about it. But MongoClient sometimes also causes this issue that i mentioned.

thank you for your observation, userService code is added on post.

Your post help me to solve the problem, final solution is given below

I have pointed out many  missing points except the one that you need that somehow I skipped . But still thank you for your appreciation.
